# Can I use a PayPal and 2Checkout integration in Pakistan to receive international payments?

Tags: paypal

I live in Pakistan. I just made a Django E-Commerce Website and wish to set up a payment integration with PayPal (Paypal is not available for transactions) to take money transactions from other countries.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s a customer service enquiry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To receive PayPal payments you typically need a PayPal Business account from a supported country. Since Pakistan is not one of those supported countries, it will be difficult for you to obtain one and especially withdraw any funds later.

Comment: Yeah ...! Sooooooooooooo, can I use a VPN to create it and then use it .... huh it looks funny but may be or if I say someone my relative out of the country and than use his account....